# How to watch history for Electron and VueJS app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, html5-history

I want to be able to keep an icon dim if there are no forward history states. It would look something like < > and the right one would be dim if you couldn't go forward in the browser history anymore.

This is the code I have, but it doesn't work.

```
<template>
    <div class="history-container" :class="pinned ? 'pinned' : ''">
       <div class="go-back-button" v-html="arrowLeftSVG" @click="go(-1)"></div>
       <div class="forward-button" v-html="arrowLeftSVG" @click="go(1)" :class="!forwardExists ? 'disabled' : ''"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {  
    computed: {
        forwardExists: () => {
            return window.history.state !== null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        go (num) {
            window.history.go(num)
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.history-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 51px;
    z-index: 1;
    &.pinned {
        margin-left: 260px;
    }
}

.forward-button {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.forward-button, .go-back-button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 51px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

EDIT: This is a single-page-app. Just thought you might want to know that.

Comment: There are mutliple things to consider here. First of all `window.history.state` is not set on a vue instance, therefore there is no reactivity on this variable. Second, you mentioned that this is a SPA. You are using `window.history.go` to change the current page, which will result in a full page reload (not very SPAish).. If you are using the vue router, take a look at the vue-router `push` method.

Comment: I am using pushState in my router

Comment: `router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (router.isNavigating) {
    router.isNavigating = false
  }
  else {
    history.pushState(null, '')
  }
  next()
  console.log(router)
})`

Comment: This allows me to add history to the history object and when I go(-1) or go(1) I can actually go there instead of going to the page that loaded before the SPA loaded. But thanks for the aside. BTW, I knew that window.history wasn't a Vue component. I was asking for an answer to the problem. Not the reason why the problem exists, but thanks again.

Comment: I think what I'm going to do is add a popstate listener to the document and record the length of the history on the $store. If the length of the history doesn't change then I know that the user clicked the back button. At that point, I can undim the forward button.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

First I made a new property on the router so that I can set it when the user clicks the "back" or "forward" button

in my router.vue I have this

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (router.isNavigating) {
    router.isNavigating = false
  }
  else {
    history.pushState(null, '')
  }
  next()
})

router['isNavigating'] = false
router['direction'] = false
```

Then in my template I have this.

```
<div class="go-back-container">
    <div class="go-back-button" v-html="arrowLeftSVG" @click="go(0)"></div>
    <div class="history-text">back</div>
</div>
    <div class="forward-container" :class="$root.forwardEntries !== 0 ? '' : 'dim'" v-show="!isMobile">
    <div class="forward-button" v-html="arrowLeftSVG" @click="go(1)"></div>
    <div class="history-text">forward</div>
</div>
```

And Finally, in my main.js mounted hook, I have:

```
var pushState = history.pushState
history.pushState = function (state) {
  // create an onpushstate listener
  pushState.apply(history, arguments)

  if (typeof history.onpushstate === 'function') {
      history.onpushstate({ state: state })
  }
}

window.history.onpushstate = (e) => {
    this.forwardEntries = 0
    // if we are pushing state, then we know that the user 
    // has navigated forward in history
    // so we know that the user can't go forward
}

window.onpopstate = (e) => {
    if (router.direction === 'back') {
        console.log('back')
        this.forwardEntries++
    }
    else if (router.direction === 'forward') {
         console.log('forward')
         this.forwardEntries--
    }
}
```

Comment: I gotta edit this post lol. This is from waaaaaay back when I was a noob lol.